# How can I plot a color histogram with all 3 channels (red, green, blue) in the same figure in python?

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib, histogram

I used the code below to read an image then generate a color histogram for it in python.

```
path = r"G:\3Y_individualProject\farm_colormap1.jpg"
colormap1 = cv2.imread(path)
colormap1=cv2.cvtColor(colormap1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
plt.imshow(colormap1)
chans=cv2.split(colormap1)
colors=("b", "g", "r")
plt.figure()
plt.title("Color histogram")
plt.xlabel("Bins")
plt.ylabel("Number of pixels")
for (chan, c) in zip(chans, colors):
    hist=cv2.calcHist([chan], [0], None, [256], [0,256])
    plt.plot(hist, color=c)
    plt.xlim([0,256])
    plt.show()
```

However, it plots 3 color channels (red, green, blue) into 3 different figures like this

[image]
[image]
[image]
So how can I plot them in the same figure? Thank you!

Comment: Move `plt.show()` outside of the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call `plt.show()` twice. Therefore after executing one part of the loop it shows and then it does the loop again and it shows the second one.

The fixed version is as follows:

```
path = r"G:\3Y_individualProject\farm_colormap1.jpg"
colormap1 = cv2.imread(path)
colormap1=cv2.cvtColor(colormap1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
plt.imshow(colormap1)
chans=cv2.split(colormap1)
colors=("b", "g", "r")
plt.figure()
plt.title("Color histogram")
plt.xlabel("Bins")
plt.ylabel("Number of pixels")
for (chan, c) in zip(chans, colors):
    hist=cv2.calcHist([chan], [0], None, [256], [0,256])
    plt.plot(hist, color=c)
    plt.xlim([0,256])
plt.show()
```